# How do I serialize UniqueIdentifier to string and back

Tags: corda

I need to pass a `UniqueIdentifier` as a string between two services. Unfortunately `UniqueIdentifier#toString` and `UniqueIdentifier.fromString` do not work well if an `externalId` is set.

What is the canonical way of serializing and deserializing a `UniqueIdentifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Corda's library to create a `UniqueIdentifier` set with a custom external id, you can see that the `toString()` will generate a pattern of `${externalId}_$id` i.e `dummyExternalId_10ed0cc3-7bdf-4000-b610-595e36667d7d`.

So to covert it back to UniqueIdentifier from that string, just split by delimiter of `_`

```
if (p.text.contains("_")) {
            val ids = p.text.split("_")
            //Create UUID object from string.
            val uuid: UUID = UUID.fromString(ids[1])
            //Create UniqueIdentifier object using externalId and UUID.
            return UniqueIdentifier(ids[0], uuid)
        }
```

Link [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/06d27b57c1c4b43b7e79ed4083c30939f16ebee9/tools/shell/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/tools/shell/SerializationSupport.kt#L31)

If you have underscore in external id, you'll probably need your own function.

```
val potentialIds = input.split("_")

// Drop last one and stitch back the external id
val externalIdString = potentialIds.dropLast(1).joinToString("_")

// Last one is the UUID
val uuid = UUID.fromString(potentialIds.last())
val finalUniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(externalIdString, uuid)
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it *is* the official way

Comment: Weird but that parser seems to brake if external Id contains an underscore

Comment: You'll probably need a custom function for that. Added in the answer. @voddan

Comment: Or rather, Corda needs to fix a bug ;)

Comment: Btw your second implementation also fails if there were no externalID in the initial UI. I think a .ifEmpty { null } in the end of 4th line should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Wait a sec, do you have to create an UniqueIdentifier for some business of yours? In that case you can just create a UniqueIdentifier from scratch and pass it as a variable between services (transactions accept external attachment).

If you have to "extract" the uniqueIdentifier of your State I don't think that is possible.

If I missed the point I apologize in advance :D

Comment: The UniqueIdentifier has already been created, then stored outside Corda, and now I want to pass it back.

Comment: If you want to get a data back into the network you have to use Oracles, I think there are some tutorials on the corda.doc page